# Override CSS rule starting with period

Tags: html, css

I have a css rule that I am having trouble overriding:

```
body {
    font: 12px/1.45em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.116;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #cccccc url(/images/bg_grad.jpg) fixed;
    background: #71828A;
}
.popup_text {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px/1.45em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

<body class="popup_text">
```

I want to override `popup_text` with a different `font-size`.  Here is what I have tried:

```
.popup_text.big {
    font-size: 16px;
}

<body class="big">
```

and

```
.popup_text .big {
    font-size: 16px;
}

<body class="big">
```

and

```
<body class="popup_text.big">
```

When I do this, the browser seem to ignore `.popup_text` rule completely and reverts to the css definition for `body`.

What is the best way to override the `.popup_text` rule where I just want to increase the `font-size` that is used with `.popup_text`?

Comment: You could of done it with just `.popup_text` if it is after the initial rules

Comment: I needed to preserve font-size: 12px for popup_text.  Under certain conditions, I wanted popup_text with 16px font-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector `.popup_text.big` (no space between classes) will match any element that has both the `popup_text` and `big` CSS classes.

The CSS selector `.popup_text .big` (space between classes) will match any element with the class `big` that is a descendant of an element with the class `popup_text`.

However none of the examples you provided have a body element with those two classes. The closest you came was `<body class="popup_text.big">`, but that lacks the space between classes and has an extraneous period. To apply multiple classes, you'd write `<body class="popup_text big">` or `<body class="big popup_text">`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3yoszxh9/)**

You could also have just added your font property modification to the end of the `popup_text` rule you had, since the browser will use the last of any duplicate properties with a rule you specify.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ykst3swk/)**

Comment: class="popup_text big" worked great.  I wanted to preserve popup_text rule while adding big under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`.popup_text.big` matches an element that is a member of the class `popup_text` and also a member of the class `big`.

`<body class="big">` only matches half of those conditions. You would need `<body class="big popup_text">`

---

`.popup_text .big` matches an element that is a member of the class `big` that has an ancestor that is a member of the class `big`.

You would need `<html class="popup_text"> ... <body class="big">`

---

`<body class="popup_text.big">` has a class name with a `.` in it. You would need to escape it (`.popup_text\.big`) in the selector.